# Count Number of Possible Sequences

Tags: algorithm, permutation, counting

I recently came across the following question during an interview.

There is a sequence `{a1, a2, a3, a4, ..... aN}`.
A run is the maximal strictly increasing or strictly decreasing continuous part of the sequence.
Eg. If we have a sequence `{1,2,3,4,7,6,5,2,3,4,1,2}`
We have 5 possible runs `{1,2,3,4,7}`, `{7,6,5,2}`, `{2,3,4}`, `{4,1}` and `{1,2}`.

Given four numbers `N`, `M`, `K`, `L`. Count the number of possible sequences of `N` numbers that has exactly `M` runs, each of the number in the sequence is less than or equal to `K` and difference between the adjacent numbers is less than equal to `L`.

Comment: And how did you try to solve it?

Comment: And especially, where is the question??

Comment: The third paragraph has the actual question. I just edited to separate the paragraphs appropriately.

Comment: I'm assuming all the numbers must be non-negative?  Otherwise there are infinitely possibly values for the first number.

Comment: The third paragraph has the actual question. I just edited to separate the paragraphs appropriately.

Comment: That's not a question. Even if it's turned into a question, where is the initiative?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Looks like numbers must be positive integers. No zeros either I guess.

Comment: I dunno, I do all these interview questions but I never get a job ...

Comment: Can you give some actual answers for simple cases so we can calibrate our interpretation of your words?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a way to analyze it analytically and come up with an O(1) solution.  However, that will take someone much smarter than me to figure out :) Here is a dynamic-programming solution.

*I am assuming for this solution that all values must be positive.  Further, I assume that all values in the sequence must be unequal to the prior value.  Both of these conditions seem implied, but never explicitly stated, in the question.*

---

First, let's alter the problem slightly so that, in addition to `N`, `M`, `K`, and `L`, we are also given the value of the last term in the sequence, a<sub>n</sub>.  Let's also add *yet another* variable `I`, which represents whether that last term was part of an increasing or decreasing sequence.  Then we'll define a function `F` to return the number of possible sequences given *all* of those values.

```
N = number of values in sequence
M = number of "runs" in the sequence
K = max value allowed
L = max difference between adjacent sequence terms
I = whether the last term is increasing or decreasing
an = last term in the sequence
FK,L(N,M,I,an) = number of possible sequences, given all these values
```

Now if we had a way to calculate `F`, we could just sum over all possible values of a<sub>n</sub> *(from 1 to K)* and `I` to get the answer to your problem.

---

Let's assume I = "increasing."  We want to express **F<sub>K,L</sub>(N,M,"increasing",a<sub>n</sub>)** in terms of a "smaller" value of `F`, so we can recursively calculate values of `F` to obtain the final value.  We'll do this by summing the value of `F` over all possible values of **a<sub>n-1</sub>**; that is, we essentially say that `F` is equal to the number valid sequences of length `N-1` that *could* end in **a<sub>n</sub>**, then we imagine appending **a<sub>n</sub>** to each of them.

Because we know **a<sub>n</sub>** is part of an increasing sequence *(I = "increasing")*, we know that **a<sub>n-1</sub> < a<sub>n</sub>** *(we'll get to the other case soon)*.  We also know that **a<sub>n-1</sub>** must be within `L` of **a<sub>n-1</sub>**; thus **max(1, a<sub>n</sub> - L) <= a<sub>n-1</sub> < a<sub>n</sub>**.

We now have two cases to consider, depending on whether the previous term **a<sub>n-1</sub>** was increasing or decreasing:

1. **a<sub>n-1</sub>** was *increasing*.  Then we are still increasing, so the value of `F` we're interested in is
   **F<sub>K,L</sub>(N-1,M,"increasing",a<sub>n-1</sub>)**.
2. **a<sub>n-1</sub>** was *decreasing*.  **a<sub>n</sub>** is now *increasing*, so there's now going to be one more "run" of values.  Thus, the value of `F` we're interested in is
   **F<sub>K,L</sub>(N-1,M-1,"decreasing",a<sub>n-1</sub>)**.

We sum all these cases for all possible values of **a<sub>n-1</sub>** to get the value of **F<sub>K,L</sub>(N,M,"increasing",a<sub>n</sub>)**.  We can find **F<sub>K,L</sub>(N,M,"decreasing",a<sub>n</sub>)** in a similar manner, only we limit **a<sub>n-1</sub>** to **a<sub>n</sub> < a<sub>n-1</sub> <= min(K, a<sub>n</sub>+L)**, and we subtract 1 from `M` in case #1 rather than case #2.

---

Finally, we state the base cases.  **F<sub>K,L</sub>(N,M,I,a<sub>n</sub>):  0 if M < 1 or M > N; 1 if N = 1**.

Then, as I mentioned above, just sum over all values of `I` and **a<sub>n</sub>** in **F<sub>K,L</sub>(N,M,I,a<sub>n</sub>)** to get the answer to your original problem.  The runtime complexity is `O(KMN)`

Answer (score 0):

I would break the problem down as follows. The runs must alternate between increasing and decreasing, so the important numbers are where the direction turns around. For the example above, the important numbers are `1 - 7 - 2 - 4 - 2` as marked below:

```
(1,2,3,4,7,6,5,2,3,4,1,2)
 x       x     x   x x x
```

Suppose you already have given the positions and values of these turning points, e.g. you have

```
(1,7,2,4,1,2)
```

Then we want to count the number of ways to pad in between numbers. This depends only on `N` and `L` because we're already using the constraints from `K` and `M` to make that skeleton. The rule here is that the missing numbers are monotone between the given numbers and don't jump by more than `L`. That's an easy counting problem (details to come later).

Next count the number of skeletons, which depends only on `K` and `M` (the count for filling them out might be 0 based on `N` and `L`). What do we know about these? Without the gaps, this has to be an alternating sequence (up-down-up-down) of length `M+1` with values between `1` and `K`. Again, this is [well studied](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation) and not hard to count.

The only hesitation that I have for this approach is that there isn't an easy way to combine these two counts, so it won't give a clean formula. However, it's still a great improvement over enumerating solutions exhaustively, and perhaps the idea can be improved further to give a closed or cleanly recursive formula.

Comment: I considered this, but it seemed like a dead-end.  For instance, how do you reconcile the fact that some sets of values are invalid for some "skeletons" but not others (ex. if `L=2` and your first two values are 1 and 7, then the first two positions must be at least 3 indicies apart)?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I see no need to "reconcile" that... sometimes there are 0 solutions. I agree that this isn't the cleanest answer.

Comment: What I meant was, you need to take that into consideration, or your counting equation will be counting "skeletons" that aren't actually valid solutions.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You have to add up the total number of paddings for each skeleton. I don't see what special considerations are needed when adding 0s.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "adding 0's" - my concern is not with adding a combination that we know has 0 solutions, it's with counting an invalid sequence as a valid one accidentally.  I guess you'll have to write out a more explicit formula, because I really don't see how you can use the "alternating permutations" formula in light of the fact that, given the combination of positions for what you call the "important numbers," only a subset of the alternating permutations will be valid, depending on the exact positions given.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

The post tags seem to suggest that this was a phone interview, which means you are expected to know about Eulerian numbers. More specifically the number of permutations of N with a total of M ascending plus descending runs is given by 2*A(N,M/2-1) also written as

```
2*  /     N   \
    \ M/2 - 1 /
```

which can be solved recursively as 2 times the result of:

```
let x = M/2-1; then
A(n,x)=(n-x)*A(n-1,x-1)+(x+1)*A(n-1,x)
```

The two further restrictions, k and L, are to control the form of the permutation cycles. for example, if L=3 then the permutation {9,1,3,6,2} is not allowed because in the cycle [1,2,9], 9 is too big.

Your resume probably paints you as an expert on combinatorics, which simply means you need to review your school notes. Anyway, I hope this sets you on your way.

Comment: *"The two further restrictions, k and L, are to control the form of the permutation cycles."* - right, which is why this approach does not actually work...